# Bootstrap - match vertical column heights that are not in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a rather complicated website design I'm working on. I have the following 4 containers (I call them that, but they don't have the `.container` class)

In a wide screen layout:

[image]

In a narrow screen layout:

[image]

The issue I'm having is matching the total height of the white, grey and yellow containers with the blue container on a wide screen layout:

[image]

[image]

The grey and yellow containers are in a `.row` `div`, so adding the style `{ display: inline-flex }` makes them the same height on a narrow screen layout:

[image]

However, this moves them completely to the side in the wide screen layout and this wouldn't match the combined white, grey and yellow containers with the blue container:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/1195/    try this

Comment: @BalvantAhir: this could work to match the grey and yellow containers' heights since they are in a row, but not to the blue container that is not in a row.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS...you'll need javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I tried a JavaScript solution, added an answer below. It works, sort off, but I really dislike it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a JavaScript solution as @Paulie_D recommended.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    NormalizeHeights();
});

window.onresize = function (event) {
    NormalizeHeights();
}

function NormalizeHeights() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {

        var carousel = $(".carousel-container");
        var dashTop = $(".dash-row-top");
        var panelLeft = $(".dash-row-bottom .panel-lightgray");
        var panelRight = $(".dash-row-bottom .panel-yellow");

        var carouselHeight = parseFloat(carousel.css('height'));
        var dashTopHeight = parseFloat(dashTop.css('height'));
        var panelLeftHeight = parseFloat(panelLeft.css('height'));
        var panelRightHeight = parseFloat(panelRight.css('height'));
        var dashBottomHeight;

        if (panelLeftHeight > panelRightHeight) {
            dashBottomHeight = panelLeftHeight;
        }
        else {
            dashBottomHeight = panelRightHeight;
        }

        if (carouselHeight > (dashTopHeight + dashBottomHeight)) {
            var difference = carouselHeight - (dashTopHeight + dashBottomHeight);
            panelLeft.css("height", (dashBottomHeight + difference));
            panelRight.css("height", (dashBottomHeight + difference));
        }
        else {
            var difference = (dashTopHeight + dashBottomHeight) - carouselHeight;
            carousel.css("height", (carouselHeight + difference));
            panelLeft.css("height", (dashBottomHeight));
            panelRight.css("height", (dashBottomHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

This works, sort off, but it's extremely unlikable in my estimation.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and the solution I found was rather ugly but worked for me.

I used divs that would clear formats BUT would their presence would be conditioned (using ng-if). Programmatically, I measured the width of the screen and set a threshold. If the width was above the threshold, I set the location of the divs, measured the height of the contents and, when applicable, forcefully changed the height of all the relevant divs to look the same (note that you would need to set this size update AFTER A TIMER is fired to let the rendering to complete).

Hope this gives you some ideas and remember: I was the first to call this **ugly**.